# Search Filtro de tienda de zapatos

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hola tengo un pqueno programa que filtra, simula una tienda de zapatos
tengo una funcion que hace el juego de filtrado pero no puedo hacer que traiga o tome 2 datos en el filtro por ejemplo si selecciona el precio mas bajo y ademas zapatillas verdes. por logica deberia traer las zapatillas verdes con el menor precio , pero si selecciono el precio trae todas las de menor precio y si coloco verde trae todas las verdes eliminando el precio[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se que tiene un operador OR pero al cambiarlo por && no funciona

Comment: Hola, podrías entregar la información de código por texto y no imagen así podrían ayudarte de mejor manera en la pregunta.

Comment: ok, tengo un data.js que es un array de objetos, creo un state para tomar los cambios de los input que son radio button con las cateogorias que seria color, precio y categoria , la paso a una funcion que permite tomar el estate si este es true devuelve o la categoria o el color pero yo quiero que tome la cateogoria y el color para que el filtro de esta tienda tenga mas sentido

Comment: Creo un if(selected) el cual le paso un filter y los datos del producto que seria los asi
 if (selected) {
      filteredProducts = filteredProducts.filter(
        ({ category, color, company, newPrice, title }) =>
          category === selected ||
          color === selected ||
          company === selected ||
          newPrice === selected ||
          title === selected
      );
    }